# Short form of if/else condition for my scenario

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to know the short form of this my php `if / else` condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0)
{
    $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
}
else
{
    $name = '';
    $flag = '0';
}
```

i have made this.. but this is not valid for `$flag`

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0 ? addslashes($_POST['name']) : ''); // returns true
```

Comment: What do you need the `addslashes` for? ಠ_ಠ I'm pretty sure you can/should do without that, at which point this mostly reduces to something like `$flag = !!strlen($name)`. – Why isn't `$flag` a boolean, and what about `$flag` in the `if` case?

Comment: `$name = (isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0 ? addslashes($_POST['name']) : ''); 
$flag = ($name == '') ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: I'm spotting a bunch of bad practices in just this short sample and think the larger code surrounding this needs to be refactored, which means we can hardly give a useful answer without more context.

Comment: @deceze `$flag` can be boolean. in if condition it is always 1.

Comment: There is no short for of `if/else`. 

[`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) is a [statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php), [`?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is an [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). They are different things and they have different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `strlen` check is superfluous; if the value doesn't exist you assign an empty string, so why check the `strlen` when at worst it's an empty string anyway?
- You should never ever use `addslashes` for anything; I sincerely doubt you're in one of the super rare situations where it makes sense to use.

Given these two things, let's use PHP's [null-coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
```

If you absolutely have to, you can wrap an `addslashes` around that expression; at worst it operates on an empty string which simply doesn't do anything.

For PHP < 7, this'll do nicely:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name') ?: '';
```

How to handle `$flag` is a bit of a mystery since you don't specify the default case. *Assuming* `$flag` should be *truthy* when `$name` isn't empty… why does it exist in the first place? Just check the emptiness of `$name`, no need to maintain a second variable in parallel for this.

But *assuming* `$flag` may already be *falsey* and acts independently of `$name`'s value, and using booleans instead of numeric string values, you can shorten it to:

```
$flag = $flag && strlen($name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the ternary operator is PHP.

The code will be like:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
```